# Mojave made my MacBook impossibly slow

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave

I have a MacBook Air 11', Early 2014 with a 1,4GHz CPU and 4Gb of RAM. I was running MacOS 10.12 without any issues, everything was fast and responsive.

Then I upgraded to MacOS 10.14, skipping MacOS 10.13. Since then, my MacBook became very slow and irresponsive. The round, colored spinning icon indicating that there is something going on is now almost omnipresent. On MacOS 10.12 I saw it rarely. Switching between apps was smooth before, now it's painful. The MacBook feels always hot, even with just the browser open. The battery burns through a lot faster.

Do I have a messed up system? If so, why didn't I have issues before upgrading to Mojave? Is there anything I can do about it?

Or is my MacBook simply too slow to run Mojave decently? Apple lists it among the devices supported by Mojave. I'm interested in the experience of other users of the same model.

Comment: How long time has passed since you upgraded? (the system will use lots of resources for some time after installation to create indexes, caches, etc.) - Please post a screenshot of Activity Monitor so that we can see which processes are using the most CPU.

Comment: I made the upgrade a few days ago. In activity monitor I found an app called "VOX Media Buttons" eating up to 70% CPU. Constantly. Now that I've deactivated Media Buttons in preferences all the symptoms seemed to have gone away. If things stay this way I will just delete this question. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Actually you should not delete the question. It is important to leave the question here for others to find if they have the same problem as you do! I have converted my comment into an answer that is listed below your question. Please mark it as accepted when you have made sure that the problem is solved on your system!

Comment: Any indication how VOX Media Buttons got on to your system? It’s rather non-standard

Comment: Voted up your question because it needs to stay! I bet there are a few who installed then removed Mojave because there were "small" issues like that spoiling their experience...

Comment: Ok, it'll stay. I thought it might be considered clutter because it wasn't the fault of Mojave after all.

Comment: VOX Media Buttons came with the VOX Media Player. They're ought to seize control of the media buttons for VOX. Seems to be a tricky thing. Sierra seemed to be fine giving up control of the media buttons, but Mojave was fighting back it seems. There was also a lot of hard drive activity and /var was getting huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise using Activity Monitor to examine the CPU usage of the running processes. There's most likely a process taking up huge amounts of CPU-time responsible for slowing down the rest of the system.

When you have identified the process, decide whether to remove the program, look for updates, contacting the developer or otherwise rectify the issue.

Note: Right after installing Mojave the system will be slower than usually because it is creating Spotlight indexes, caches, and other types of one-off computations. Please wait a day or two for this to complete.

Answer (score 0):

btw are your disk space running real low, e.g. less than 100MB left?

My case is the core dump ate up all available HD space til only 60MB left! and my Mac totally frozen (possibly due to lack of swap space).

The solution is to force shutdown and boot into Recovery mode (command-R) and launch terminal to

```
sudo rm /cores/core.*
```

manually.

You can follow the info on this page to entirely turn OFF core dump
http://krypted.com/mac-security/core-dumps-in-mac-os-x/